# create CheckBox on button press

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am trying to create a checkbox, when a button is clicked, but I always get this error:

`Error:(30, 52) error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context`

This the code which creates the error:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

            CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
            myCheckBox.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            myLayout.addView(myCheckBox);
        }
    });

}
```

What causes the incompatible types?

Comment: use `NameActivity.this`. `this` in your case is the `OnClickListener` which is not a context

Comment: You are my hero! I'm new here, can i rate you, or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you are passing context as View.OnClickListener. Change

`new CheckBox(this)`

to:

```
new CheckBox(v.getContext());
```